# How to put Combo Boxes generated by the Windows Form Designer in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a bunch of different ComboBoxes that were made with the windows form Designer I would like to be able to access them by index, so that I could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++)
{
    ComboBoxes[i].visible = false;
}
```

I tried putting them in an array of ComboBoxes, but this creates an array of nulls.

```
private ComboBox[] ComboBoxes;

public MainForm()
{
     ComboBoxes = new ComboBox[] {ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3};
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you make your array of `ComboBox` after `InitializeComponent` is called.

```
private ComboBox[] ComboBoxes;

public MainForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     ComboBoxes = new ComboBox[] {ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3};
}
```

Prior to this all of the windows form designer objects will be null because they are only first instantiated in `InitializeComponent`.